# Dummy variables to indicate the week of year for linear regression? Is that a good idea

Tags: r, linear-regression, dummy-variable

I have a problem with my data. I want to have a dummy variable to indicate the week number in the year as a predictor. When I look into it, it seems that I need to have 51 dummy variables, and my results become strange when running the code in R.
How can I add dummy variables to indicate the week of year for linear regression as a predictor? And is that a good idea?

I have tried to do this in R, but my results become somewhat wrong.

Comment: If you need advice on modeling your data, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead where statistical questions are on topic. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. Or at the very least share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the code you tried that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. We currently have no idea exactly what you tried.